# Portability of hosted NoSQL solutions

Tags: sql, mongodb, google-cloud-datastore, database, nosql

Coming from an SQL guy, I'm looking to use NoSQL in production. One thing I noticed is that transferring from one provider to another is not going to be as easy as importing/exporting in "normal" SQL. Correct me if I'm wrong but it appears each flavor of NoSQL has its own "scheme".

My question is, say I chose Google Datastore today, then some time in the future I decide to move my data to Amazon DynamoDB or some hosted MongoDB service, for whatever reason it may be (price/performance/etc).. Do I need to code my own transition script or is there a standard way/tool to move across different NoSQL solutions (like simple import/export in traditional SQL DBs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you guessed right. The databases you listed are all *wildly* different. Consequently, there is no automated way of moving data between them (that I heard of). Nor is there any sense.

MongoDB, for example, supports quite rich set of operations, compared to which the key-value API of DynamoDB looks primitive. So unless your app only uses "get_item/put_item" operations, you can't really switch between different NoSQL databases.